# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aruco_marker.aruco_subscriber'

Tags: ros2, package, module

I created a package in ros2 named aruco_marker using this command `ros2 pkg create --build-type ament_python aruco_marker` and created a folder named scripts inside the package, then inside the scripts folder i have a python file named aruco_subscriber.py...
the setup.py file

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

    package_name = 'aruco_marker'
    
    setup(
        name=package_name,
        version='0.0.0',
        packages=find_packages(exclude=['test']),
        data_files=[
            ('share/ament_index/resource_index/packages',
                ['resource/' + package_name]),
            ('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml']),
        ],
        install_requires=['setuptools'],
        zip_safe=True,
        maintainer='pc',
        maintainer_email='pc@todo.todo',
        description='TODO: Package description',
        license='TODO: License declaration',
        tests_require=['pytest'],
        entry_points={
            'console_scripts': [
            'aruco_subscriber_node = aruco_marker.aruco_subscriber:main'
            ],
        },
    )
```

when i run the `ros2 run aruco_marker aruco_subscriber_node` the terminal shows this error

```
ros2 run aruco_marker aruco_subscriber_node 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pc/ros2_ws/install/aruco_marker/lib/aruco_marker/aruco_subscriber_node", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('aruco-marker==0.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'aruco_subscriber_node')())
  File "/home/pc/ros2_ws/install/aruco_marker/lib/aruco_marker/aruco_subscriber_node", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 171, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aruco_marker.aruco_subscriber'
[ros2run]: Process exited with failure 1
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The python package that's installed is assumed to be inside the `aruco_marker` folder (inside the package there should be a folder with the same name as the package itself).
Inside this folder you can put whatever you need as with any python package.
In your situation, you should put the `scripts` folder inside the `aruco_marker` folder as follows:

```bash
aruco_marker
   -setup.py
   -package.xml
   -...
   -aruco_marker
        -scripts
            -aruco_subscriber.py
```

Now in the setup file you can add the entry as follows:

```py
'aruco_subscriber_node = aruco_marker.scripts.aruco_subscriber:main'
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your reply @Zein... the problem is where the python file should be placed...i moved the python file from the `scripts` folder and placed in the `aruco_marker` folder where the `__init__.py` is located...after i moved the file..no issues or warnings when i run the node. I think your suggestion also works, but idk. Hope it helps.